# Execute all rules in drl file with element of arraylist

Tags: java, drools

I am having list of rules which is working on element inside List.

Example :
List of Student as input to drl file ( size will be around 40)

Drl File :

rule-1 
 when   student name is ‘Ravi’

rule-2
 when   student salary is 1000

rule-3 
 when   student college is IIT

....... as so on ( around 50 rules )

so if I iterate list in all the rules to check condition it will degrade performance.
Is it possible that elements of List will be executed on all the rules so that my list will be iterated only once.

Pls let me know what will be best solution for above case

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is probably to iterate your array outside the rules and insert the objects it contains into the session:

```
//Java
List<Student> students = //get the list of Students
KieSession ksession = //create session

for (Student s : students){
    ksession.insert(s);
}
ksession.fireAllRules();

//DRL
rule "rule-1"
when
    Student(name == "Ravi")
then
    //...
end

...
```

The other option is to insert the list into the session and have a rule that will iterate over the elements and insert them:

```
//Java
List<Student> students = //get the list of Students
KieSession ksession = //create session

ksession.insert(students);
ksession.fireAllRules();

//DRL
rule "Insert Students"
when
    $l: List()
    $s: Student() from $l
then
    insert($s);
end

rule "rule-1"
when
    Student(name == "Ravi")
then
    //...
end

...
```

The problem with the second approach is that things can get messy if you get more than on `List` in your session. Good practices state that is usually not a good idea to have classes from the JDK as facts (of course there are exceptions).

Hope it helps,